# php curl download file in download manager

Tags: php, curl, download

i have a problem with a file output, it is really small, like around 4kb and file said "400 - Bad Request".

from source, the correct size is 28.2mb.

```
$url = 'http://mozilla.isu.net.sa/firefox/releases/7.0.1/mac/en-US/Firefox%207.0.1.dmg';
$curl = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);  
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, 1); 
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 360);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'temp/cookie.txt'); 
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, 'temp/cookie.txt');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 10);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.7.5) Gecko/20041107 Firefox/1.0');

$curl_out = curl_exec($curl);

curl_close($curl);

$filename = explode('/', $url);
$filename = $filename[count($filename)-1];

header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$filename.'"');

print($curl_out);
```

If It cant handle bigger file, other method: i want to download from php with cookie that forward to source link... then how?

Comment: try vardumping curl_out and look for errors in file retrieval

Comment: @jancha i tried with 'echo var_dump($curl_out);' output: `<body>string(349) "<!--?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?-->


 
  <title>400 - Bad Request</title>
 
 
  <h1>400 - Bad Request</h1>
 

"
</body>`

Comment: Why don't you just redirect the user to that download. If the file is 28+megs, you'll be storing all that in memory before dumping it out which is wasting server resources.

Comment: @Jabbany how can i download with cookie after forward to link in download manager?

Comment: @user453089 - as you can see from the vardump, you are experiencing problems with the actual download of the file. so make sure that url, method (get/post), params (session?) are all ok.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you are trying to do, but from what i see, you are downloading the file then offering the user to download it again, so for each request to this link you will have to download it again. So there is too much overhead.

Here is a simpler solution:

```
<a href="http://mozilla.isu.net.sa/firefox/releases/7.0.1/mac/en-US/Firefox%207.0.1.dmg">Click here to download</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Download the file using your browser,observe, copy and replicate all the headers and cookies (use tamper data(firefox) to see the headers)

and for downloading a file, i will suggest you to try something like this along with what you have already done.

```
$url  = 'http://www.example.com/a-large-file.zip';
$path = '/path/to/a-large-file.zip';

$fp = fopen($path, 'w');

$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);

$data = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);
fclose($fp);
```

Apart from that, i tried your link and download starts directly, so the code above should be sufficient.